# ggplot legend slashes

Tags: r, ggplot2

This must have annoyed someone in the past so excuse me if this is a duplicate and I will remove it.  Slashes across legends when using `geom_bar` can be annoying. e.g.:

```
x  <- c("a","b")
y  <- c(1,2)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
a  <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,fill=x))
a + geom_bar(colour="black") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "black"))
```

[image]

When I use coloured bars I use this work around, plotting bars without colours first e.g.

```
a + geom_bar() + geom_bar(colour="black",show_guide=FALSE) +
 scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "black"))
```

However when the fill is white this leaves an unsatisfying empty white box in the legend without a border. e.g.

[image]

I have fixed this in the past manually using graphics software but now I think this must be of use to enough people to ask a question here.  Can we make `ggplot` plot the legend with the black outline only but without the slash?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this,

```
 a + geom_bar() + geom_bar(colour="black",show_guide=FALSE) +
 scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "black")) + 
 opts(legend.key = theme_rect(fill = 'black'))
```

gave me this,
[image]
thanks to [this site](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Legend-Attributes).

Alos, you get the same result using `colour` instead of `fill` (it might be argued that one is better than).

```
a + geom_bar() + geom_bar(colour="black",show_guide=FALSE) + 
scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "black")) + 
opts(legend.key = theme_rect(colour = 'black'))
```

**Important note**: In modern versions of ggplot2 `opts` has been deprecated and replaced with `theme`, and `theme_rect` has been replaced by `element_rect`.

Comment: `opts(legend.key = theme_rect` it's so simple!

Comment: @user1317221_G, that's the beauty of it.

Comment: For me on the windows gui it only give a line up the right side.  let me try it in Rstudio.

Comment: Nope I needed to increase the size

Comment: @TylerRinker can you elaborate on the size issue?  I'm seeing the same behavior with what appears to be only a line on the right hand side of the legend sqaures.

Comment: The problem persists for me when outputting to a windows graphics device but when outputting to png or pdf the output was as expected.

Answer (score 3):

No that's what gives it it's outline.  If you use a gray instead of white (with your trick) it's more distinguishable.  You could also add background color to the legend to make it more distinguishable and keep it white.  See the bottom of this page for more detail:

http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Legends%20(ggplot2)/

i wish there were a less hackish way to do this.

Comment: I believe the solution in the cookbook is more general. This question deals more with the issue of legend.key than removing the slashes.

Comment: @Martin you're responding to a post that is over a year old so a bit has changed since then including the cookbook.  Also it has everything to do with removing the slashes.  See the title of the question and the content. At the time all the fancy legend stuff didn't exist or was just introduced (ggplot2 0.9.0).

Comment: I understand the post is old, the thing is I had to deal with this same issue and the cookbook gave me a more general answer. I mean, I followed your link and it helped me more than the accepted answer.

Comment: @Martin Gotcha.  That is useful for future searchers.