# Legend interactions with multiple plots from different dataframes: How does one deal with this interaction?

Tags: r, ggplot2

A reproducible subset of my dataframes that contain data I wish to plot:

```
# Import library
library(ggplot2)

# Data Example--------------
MCsubsetDT1112 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(15280, 15280, 15281, 15281, 
15282, 15282, 15283, 15283, 15284, 15284, 15285, 15285, 15286, 
15286, 15287, 15287, 15288, 15288, 15289, 15289), class = "Date"), 
    SubstrateConcat = structure(c(1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 
    5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("B_B", 
    "C_C", "C1_C", "C2_C", "S_S", "S_S "), class = "factor"), 
    SiteSub = c("SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.S_S", "SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.S_S", 
    "SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.S_S", "SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.S_S", "SW_MC.B_B", 
    "SW_MC.S_S", "SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.S_S", "SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.S_S", 
    "SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.S_S", "SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.S_S", "SW_MC.B_B", 
    "SW_MC.S_S"), WaterType = c("WarmWater", "WarmWater", "WarmWater", 
    "WarmWater", "WarmWater", "WarmWater", "WarmWater", "WarmWater", 
    "WarmWater", "WarmWater", "WarmWater", "WarmWater", "WarmWater", 
    "WarmWater", "WarmWater", "WarmWater", "WarmWater", "WarmWater", 
    "WarmWater", "WarmWater"), Mean = c(5.134, 0.678, 5.153, 
    0.755, 5.126, 0.347, 6.687, 1.098, 6.647, 0.932, 6.145, 0.469, 
    5.629, 0.342, 5.36, 0.036, 5.392, 0.107, 5.941, 0.376)), .Names = c("Date", 
"SubstrateConcat", "SiteSub", "WaterType", "Mean"), row.names = 3100:3119, class = "data.frame")

MCsubsetTemp1112 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(15340, 15341, 15342, 15343, 
15344, 15345, 15346, 15347, 15348, 15349, 15350, 15351, 15352, 
15353, 15354, 15355, 15356, 15357, 15358, 15359), class = "Date"), 
    SubstrateConcat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("B_B", 
    "C_C", "C1_C", "C2_C", "S_S", "S_S "), class = "factor"), 
    SiteSub = c("SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.B_B", 
    "SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.B_B", 
    "SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.B_B", 
    "SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.B_B", "SW_MC.B_B", 
    "SW_MC.B_B"), WaterType = c("WarmWater", "WarmWater", "WarmWater", 
    "WarmWater", "WarmWater", "WarmWater", "WarmWater", "WarmWater", 
    "WarmWater", "WarmWater", "WarmWater", "WarmWater", "WarmWater", 
    "WarmWater", "WarmWater", "WarmWater", "WarmWater", "WarmWater", 
    "WarmWater", "WarmWater"), Mean = c(28.115, 28.097, 28.028, 
    27.937, 27.824, 27.743, 27.678, 27.545, 27.465, 27.401, 27.246, 
    27.169, 27.155, 26.937, 26.493, 25.958, 25.502, 25.329, 25.247, 
    25.171)), .Names = c("Date", "SubstrateConcat", "SiteSub", 
"WaterType", "Mean"), row.names = 1753:1772, class = "data.frame")
```

I plotted the data with the temperature data as lines (from `MCsubsetTemp1112`) and delta-T as bars (from `MCsubsetDT1112`). I mapped WaterType to `color` (labeled in legend as "Water Type"), SubstrateConcat to `linetype` (labeled in legend as "Substrate"), and in the `geom_bar` plot, I mapped SubstrateConcat to `fill` (labeled in legend as delta-T Substrate).

```
Plot1 <- ggplot(MCsubsetTemp1112, aes(x=Date, y=Mean, group=SiteSub,  color=WaterType, linetype=SubstrateConcat)) + 
  geom_line(size=1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=20, linetype="dashed") +
  scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%b %Y")) +
  ylim(-5,35) +
  labs(x= "Date", y=expression("Temperature  " ( degree~C)), color="Water Type", linetype="Substrate") +
  ggtitle("Daily Mean Temperatures of Two Sites and delta-T") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "dashed", "dotdash"), labels=c("Bottom", "Column", "Surface")) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("darkblue", "maroon"), labels=c("non-Warm", "Warm")) +
  guides(linetype=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA)),
         color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA))) +
  theme(
    plot.title=element_text(color="black", size=16, face="bold"),
    axis.line=element_line(color="black"),
    axis.title=element_text(color="black", size=16),
    axis.text=element_text(color="black", size=14),
    panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"),
    legend.background=element_blank(),
    legend.text=element_text(color="black"),
    legend.key=element_blank()) 


Plot1 + geom_bar(aes(fill=SubstrateConcat), position="dodge", stat="identity", color="black", data=MCsubsetDT1112) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "black"), labels=c("Bottom", "Surface")) +
  labs(fill="delta-T Substrate") +
  theme(legend.background=element_blank(),
        legend.text=element_text(color="black"),
        legend.key=element_blank())
```

In the code above, the `color="black"` call produced slashes through, and filled black boxes, in the "Substrate" legend which should show various `linetypes`. Using [ggplot legend slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660775/ggplot-legend-slashes?lq=1) and [Different Legends for two geom_bar with different data.frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062792/different-legends-for-two-geom-bar-with-different-data-frames), I was able to remove the black fill from the "Substrate" legend, however the slashes are still there. I cannot figure how to remove these slashes as the plot is coded above.

A workaround I came up with was to plot `geom_bar` first (see code below) using the methods in [ggplot legend slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660775/ggplot-legend-slashes?lq=1). However, I am left with the unsatisfying white box with no black outline. Furthermore, the slashes are now gone from the legend. But, a new problem arises in that the "SubstrateConcat" in the `geom_line` plot calls for three values and forces that upon the `geom_bar` plot, resulting in the error: `Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 3 needed but only 2 provided.` When an additional value, e.g. `"grey"` is added to the `scale_fill_manual` call, the plot is created but with the NA value in the "delta-T Substrate" legend.

```
Plot2 <- ggplot(MCdataDT1112, aes(x=Date, y=Mean, group=SiteSub, fill=SubstrateConcat)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", color="black", show_guide=FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "black", "grey"), labels=c("Bottom", "Surface")) +
  labs(fill="delta-T Substrate") +
  theme(legend.background=element_blank(),
        legend.text=element_text(color="black"),
        legend.key=element_rect(fill="black"))

Plot2 + geom_line(aes(group=SiteSub,  color=WaterType, linetype=SubstrateConcat), data=MCdataTemp1112, size=1) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=20, linetype="dashed") +
  scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%b %Y")) +
  ylim(-5,35) +
  labs(x= "Date", y=expression("Temperature  " ( degree~C)), color="Water Type", linetype="Substrate") +
  ggtitle("Daily Mean Temperatures of Two Sites and delta-T") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "dashed", "dotdash"), labels=c("Bottom", "Column", "Surface")) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("darkblue", "maroon"), labels=c("non-Warm", "Warm")) +
  guides(linetype=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA)),
         color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA))) +
  theme(
    plot.title=element_text(color="black", size=16, face="bold"),
    axis.line=element_line(color="black"),
    axis.title=element_text(color="black", size=16),
    axis.text=element_text(color="black", size=14),
    panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"),
    legend.background=element_blank(),
    legend.text=element_text(color="black"),
    legend.key=element_blank())
```

How can I modify my code such that the legend produce for the first plot is not modified by the second plot. I am new to R and ggplot2; I'm still figuring out exactly what happens when data are plotted such as I have done above.

I would like one or both of the following:

Plot 1 without the slashes through the legends.

Plot 2 with the delta-T legend that shows only white for "Bottom" and black for "Surface" with the bars outlined.

Please explain what is happening that one plot modifies the legend of the plot before it. Thank you!

Comment: This is a very small subset of my data, but I think it's enough to understand what I'm looking for. If not, I can edit/paste more data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the full data that you provided for me in chat, if I run this:

```
MCsubsetDT1112 <- read.csv("~/Downloads/MCsubsetDT1112.csv")
MCsubsetTemp1112 <- read.csv("~/Downloads/MCsubsetTemp1112.csv")

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = MCsubsetDT1112, 
           aes(x=as.Date(Date,"%m/%d/%Y"), y=Mean, group=SiteSub, fill=SubstrateConcat),
           stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  geom_bar(data = MCsubsetDT1112, 
           aes(x=as.Date(Date,"%m/%d/%Y"), y=Mean, group=SiteSub, fill=SubstrateConcat),    
           stat="identity", position="dodge", color="black", show_guide=FALSE) +
  geom_line(aes(x=as.Date(Date,"%m/%d/%Y"),y=Mean,group=SiteSub,  color=WaterType, linetype=SubstrateConcat), 
            data=MCsubsetTemp1112, size=1) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=20, linetype="dashed") +
  ylim(-5,35) +
  labs(x= "Date", y=expression("Temperature  " ( degree~C)), color="Water Type", 
        linetype="Substrate",fill="delta-T Substrate") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "dashed", "dotdash"), 
                        labels=c("Bottom", "Column", "Surface")) +
  scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%b %Y")) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("darkblue", "maroon"), labels=c("non-Warm", "Warm")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "black","grey"), labels=c("Bottom", "Surface")) +
  guides(linetype=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA)),
         color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA)),
         fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = "black"))) +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(color="black", size=16, face="bold"),
        axis.line=element_line(color="black"),
        axis.title=element_text(color="black", size=16),
        axis.text=element_text(color="black", size=14),
        panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"),
        legend.background=element_blank(),
        legend.text=element_text(color="black"),
        legend.key = element_rect(colour = "black",fill = NA))
```

I get the following graph:

[image]

I added the `as.Date()` calls just because the date structure was lost when reading in from csv.